# Can I use a property to configure a URL in Explanatory Text?

Tags: orbeon

In Form Builder I have a form that includes an Explanatory Text field. The text includes a link. I want the URL for that link to be different in each environment. For my HTTP Services in forms I am using a property that I have defined as described in this [blog post](http://blog.orbeon.com/2014/04/configure-url-of-your-services-in.html).

Is it possible to use a property to configure the URL in the Explanatory Text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once [RFE 2427](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/2427) is implemented, you'll have a real solution to your problem. Right now, the text shown by `fr:explanation` is entirely static.

You could work around this though, by creating your own [custom model logic](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/custom-model-logic.html) that, on form load, replaces a certain string from the text by the value of the property you defined:

1. In Form Builder, create an Explanatory Text field, and for the URL enter `SITEURL`.
2. Still in Form Builder, edit the source of the form to remove the `xxf:readonly="true"` on the `fr-form-resources` instance. [This](https://gist.github.com/avernet/84fd8ebe1c571bc92f5e7a2d3a4c0154) is the resulting form.
3. In your `properties-local.xml` add a custom model logic: `<property as="xs:anyURI"  name="oxf.fr.detail.model.custom.*.*" value="oxf:/forms/resources/model.xml"/>`.
4. Still in the `properties-local.xml`, define the value of the placeholder with a property: `<property as="xs:string" name="com.example.siteurl" value="http://www.orbeon.com/"/>`.
5. In the `model.xml`, on form load, replace `SITEURL` by the value of the property.

And here is the content of the `model.xml`:

```
<xf:model xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
          xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms">
    <xf:action event="xforms-model-construct-done">
        <xf:action iterate="instance('fr-form-resources')/resource/text-with-link/text">
            <xf:setvalue ref="."
                         value="
                            replace(
                                .,
                                'SITEURL',
                                xxf:property('com.example.siteurl')
                            )"/>
        </xf:action>
    </xf:action>
</xf:model>
```