# How can I create a dynamic URL to open a new form?

Tags: orbeon

Do you have a recommendation for creating a dynamic URL on a form (to open another form in a new window):

1. I should use buttons and how I can to configure that?
2. I should use explanatory text and how I can configure that?

Answer (score 0):

This will be become easier when [RFE 2427](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/) is implemented. For now, you can use the technique described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43689388/can-i-use-a-property-to-configure-a-url-in-explanatory-text/43689915#43689915).

In the context of that question, the URL comes from a property. For your case, you're not saying what logic determines the dynamic URL, but I imagine that you can implement it in XPath. If it is indeed the case, you can just replace the call to `xxf:property('com.example.siteurl')` by your own XPath.

Comment: 184/5000
In the button case, I should follow the next recommendation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102328/orbeon-form-builder-hyperlink-with-dynamic-url

Please can you confirm

Comment: Correct, and I you create your own event handler for a button, I'd recommend you put that code in a [custom model logic](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/custom-model-logic.html) file.

Comment: In my case I need to pass the value of the content in a form field (url) to a button (url), in the case explained (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102328/orbeon-form-builder-hyperlink-with -dynamic-url)

<Xf: EV action: event = "DOMActivate">
<Xf: load show = "new" resource = "{xxf: bind ('url-field-bind')}" />
</ Xf: action>

The indication is that I can use the "xf: load / @ resource" statement in the value seccion (buttons?). I am new to orbeon and I am trying the solution please can you guide me how I should do this.

Comment: Correct: you can create an `<xf:action event="DOMActivate" observer="mybutton-control">`, and I recommend you put it in a [custom model logic](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/custom-model-logic.html) file. You'll also find some examples in the documentation, and of course, just let me know if anything isn't quite clear.